# How can I set a predetermined offset for Angular Material's "md-menu"?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-material

I am working with Angular Material's "md-menu" as covered in these demos: https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/menu

What I want to do is keep the bottom option of the menu always above the button you click to show the menu no matter how many entries I have set. I measured a difference of maybe 50px added to the bottom of the menu for each extra entry.

Is there a way to determine the offset depending on the number of entries in the menu and set that as the offset?

So let's say that 1 entry is "0, -50", 2 entries is "0, -100", etc.

This value just needs to be determined by some method and won't dynamically change after the page is loaded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's probably not the answer you're looking for, but depending how soon you need this feature you could wait for the `mdPanel` feature. It's been merged into master in the last couple of days, so it shouldn't be that long imo.

What's good about `mdPanel` is that you can position it easily just as you would want. You can see the basics here: https://github.com/angular/material/blob/master/src/components/panel/panel.js#L465-L497

I haven't checked whether `mdMenu` has been rebased on `mdPanel` yet (probably not *yet*), but you could just create your menu with mdPanel anyways. Here is a basic example:

```
vm.menu = function () {
    var position = $mdPanel.newPanelPosition()
        .relativeTo(document.querySelector('#menu'))
        .addPanelPosition($mdPanel.xPosition.ALIGN_START, $mdPanel.yPosition.ALIGN_BOTTOMS);

    var config = {
        templateUrl: 'widgets/menu.html',
        hasBackdrop: false,
        position: position,
        clickOutsideToClose: true,
        escapeToClose: true,
        focusOnOpen: true,
        controller: MenuController,
        controllerAs: 'vm'
    };
    $mdPanel.open(config);
}
```

You could call this function on a simple `mdButton` element, or anything you would like really.